# I cannot understand why sum(df['series']) != df['series'].sum()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm summing up the values in a series, but depending on how I do it, I get different results. The two ways I've tried are:

```
sum(df['series'])

df['series'].sum()
```

Why would they return different values?

Sample Code.

```
s = pd.Series([
0.428229
 , -0.948957
 , -0.110125
 ,  0.791305
 ,  0.113980
 ,-0.479462
 ,-0.623440
 ,-0.610920
 ,-0.135165
 , 0.090192])

 print(s.sum())
 print(sum(s))

 -1.4843630000000003
 -1.4843629999999999
```

The difference is quite small here, but in a dataset with a few thousand values, it becomes quite large.

Comment: Please provide a working example that shows that this is behaving differently.

Comment: Floats representation in binary are tricky. I would go with ```sum(s*10**10)/10**10```.

Comment: BTW, ```(s*10**10).sum()/10**10 == sum(s*10**10)/10**10``` is ```True```.

Comment: More precision is from [math.fsum](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-sum-and-fsum-in-Python) which tracks intermediate results during summation to minimize precision loss.  math.fsum(s) = -1.484363

Comment: Floating point arithmetic on a computer is inherently imprecise. Suggest you check to see if the two sums are approximately equal rather than exactly so. See question [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and this [appendix](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) to an Oracle Numerical Computation Guide titled _What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic_.

Comment: For doing arbitrary-precision floating point arithmetic, I suggest using [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/), which you can (also) get from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/mpmath/).

Comment: btw Pandas is built on Numpy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating point numbers are only accurate to a certain number of significant figures. Imagine if all of your numbers - including intermediate results - are only accurate to two significant figures, and you want the sum of the list `[100, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

- The "true" sum is **106**, but this cannot be represented since we're only allowed two significant figures;
- The "correct" answer is **110**, since that's the "true" sum rounded to 2 s.f.;
- But if we naively add the numbers in sequence, we'll first do 100 + 1 = 100 (to 2 s.f.), then 100 + 1 = 100 (to 2 s.f.), and so on until the final result is **100**.

The "correct" answer can be achieved by adding the numbers up from smallest to largest; 1 + 1 = 2, then 2 + 1 = 3, then 3 + 1 = 4, then 4 + 1 = 5, then 5 + 1 = 6, then 6 + 100 = 110 (to 2 s.f.). However, even this doesn't work in the general case; if there were over a hundred 1s then the intermediate sums would start being inaccurate. You can do even better by always adding the smallest two remaining numbers.

Python's built-in `sum` function uses the naive algorithm, while `df['series'].sum()` method uses a more accurate algorithm with a lower accumulated rounding error. [From the numpy source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2126), which pandas uses:

> For floating point numbers the numerical precision of sum (and
>       `np.add.reduce`) is in general limited by directly adding each number
>       individually to the result causing rounding errors in every step.
>       However, often numpy will use a numerically better approach (partial
>       pairwise summation) leading to improved precision in many use-cases.
>       This improved precision is always provided when no `axis` is given.

The [math.fsum function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum) uses an algorithm which is more accurate still:

> In contrast to NumPy, Python's `math.fsum` function uses a slower but
>       more precise approach to summation.

For your list, the result of `math.fsum` is `-1.484363`, which is the correctly-rounded answer.

Comment: Great post.  In addition [test of the accuracy of various methods here](https://pypi.org/project/accupy/) including Python, Numpy, [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm), math. fsum, etc.  The conclusion is math.fsum is the most accurate but slowest method.